# NameError: undefined local variable or method `request' for HomeController:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is driving me nuts. I'm using Rails 3.2.17. I can't seem to be able to use the Rails request object in my HomeController.

My HomeController code:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :json, :js

  def refresh_blog
    request.domain.include?('egg') ? (@blog_entries = Blog.fetch_entries(Blog::ED_BLOG_URL)) : (@blog_entries = Blog.fetch_entries(Blog::CS_BLOG_URL))
    respond_with(@blog_entries) do |format|
        format.html { head :not_acceptable }
    end
  end
end
```

Console output using Pry:

```
22:   #   @blog_entries =  Blog.fetch_entries
23:   #   respond_with(@blog_entries) do |format|
24:   #     format.html { head :not_acceptable }
25:   #   end
26:   # end
 => 27:   binding.pry
28:   def refresh_blog
29:     request.domain.include?('egg') ? (@blog_entries =  Blog.fetch_entries(Blog::ED_BLOG_URL)) : (@blog_entries =  Blog.fetch_entries(Blog::CS_BLOG_URL))
30:     respond_with(@blog_entries) do |format|
31:         format.html { head :not_acceptable }
32:     end

3.2.17 @ 2.1.0 (HomeController)>request
NameError: undefined local variable or method `request' for HomeController:Class
from (pry):2:in `<class:HomeController>'
3.2.17 @ 2.1.0 (HomeController)>request.domain
NameError: undefined local variable or method `request' for HomeController:Class
from (pry):3:in `<class:HomeController>'
```

What could be happening? All my research indicates that the request object should be available in controllers and views.

Answer (score 1):

The `binding.pry` statement seems to be outside of the `refresh_blog` method AFAICT from the output you pasted.

(And `request` does not exist on the `HomeController` class, but only on `HomeController` objects)